# gridview not showing values via BLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, business-logic-layer

My control doesnt return the values in my gridview.

table adapter runs the query fine and displays the data.

Here is my code from the control:

```
 categoriesBLL categoriesLogic = new categoriesBLL();
 GridView1.DataSource = categoriesLogic.GetCategories();
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

and here is my BLL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Nop.DataAccess.MegaProductMenuTableAdapters;

namespace NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.MegaProductsMenu
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
    public class categoriesBLL
    {

        private Nop_CategoryTableAdapter _categoriesAdapter = null;
        protected Nop_CategoryTableAdapter Adapter
        {
            get
            {
                if (_categoriesAdapter == null)
                    _categoriesAdapter = new Nop_CategoryTableAdapter();

                return _categoriesAdapter;
            }
        }



        [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public Nop_CategoryTableAdapter GetCategories()
        {
            return _categoriesAdapter;
        }


    }

}
```

My DAL looks like this:

[image]

If connect directly to the DAL I can get the values to show up. So i think there is something wrong with my BLL, but what could it be? I receive no error messages.

**My gridview source:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
       <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
       <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show your gridview code (source).

Comment: @DigitalAssets: added the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by asigning the datatable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Nop.DataAccess.MegaProductMenuTableAdapters;

namespace NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.MegaProductsMenu
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
    public class categoriesBLL
    {

        private Nop_CategoryTableAdapter _categoriesAdapter = null;
        protected Nop_CategoryTableAdapter Adapter
        {
            get
            {
                if (_categoriesAdapter == null)
                    _categoriesAdapter = new Nop_CategoryTableAdapter();

                return _categoriesAdapter;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public NopCommerce.Nop.DataAccess.MegaProductMenu.Nop_CategoryDataTable GetCategories()
        {
            return Adapter.GetCategories();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any columns defined? or is AutoGenerateColumns == true

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is set to true. Shall i change it to false??

Comment: No. Now I see that you assign the DataAdapter as a data source. You need to assign a DataTable or a DataView.

Comment: changing it to false made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

1. categoriesBLL categoriesLogic = new categoriesBLL();
2. GridView1.DataSource = categoriesLogic.GetCategories();
3. GridView1.DataBind();

Change the line 2 to the following

```
GridView1.DataSource = categoriesLogic.Adapter.GetCategories();
```

Comment: this doesn't solve it. I get: **'NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.MegaProductsMenu.categoriesBLL.Adapter' is inaccessible due to its protection level**

Comment: then when i change `private Nop_CategoryTableAdapter _categoriesAdapter = null;` to public and do what you said, i still get no values showing.

Comment: Please check weather calling Fill() instead of GetCategories() works or not? And set the AutoGenerateColumns to true.

Comment: It doesnt allow me to do fill

Comment: OR you can do the following  [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public Nop_Category GetCategories()
        {
            return Adapter.GetCategories();
        }

Comment: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Nop.DataAccess.MegaProductMenu.Nop_CategoryDataTable' to 'NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Nop.DataAccess.MegaProductMenuTableAdapters.Nop_CategoryTableAdapter'**